# Is clocksource tsc always unstable when the only other clocksource is jiffies?

Tags: linux, tsc

After debuging unstable tsc issue for the BIOS of my company's products, I suspect that tsc may be always unstable when the only other clocksource is jiffies.

I got the error like 
`Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -531266231 ns).` Then the kernel selected jiffies other than tsc. 
The only two clocksources are tsc and jiffies.
I tried the Linux kernel 2.6 and 3.2 both with i386 and x64. The kernel said that the CPU actually supported constant tsc and invariant tsc.

After checking the Linux source code, I find that tsc has a flag `CLOCKSOURCE_MUST_VERIFY` while jiffies does not. I guess that if there are only two clocksources, jiffies and tsc, the jiffies will be the clocksource watchdog.
However, compared to tsc, jiffies is a very poor clocksource, and therefore I suspect that tsc at this situation will always be "unstable" because there is a bad watchdog to verify it.

I also check some other system with well working tsc, and find they have other clocksources like Hpet or acpi_pm.

Therefore, how can I tell whether the tsc instability results from jiffies or some error elsewhere?

Comment: Today I tested CentOS 6.6 i386 image with minimal installation. The kernel has three time clocksources by default: tsc, acpi_pm, and jiffies. Clocksource tsc is the one being used.

Answer (score 2):

Today I tested CentOS 6.6 i386 image with minimal installation. The kernel had three time clocksources by default: `tsc acpi_pm jiffies`. Clocksource tsc was the one being used.

Then I tried `acpi=off` option and found that there were only two clocksources, `tsc jiffies`. However, tsc was not unstable and still used as the main clocksource. Therefore the watchdog jiffies will not always deny tsc.

I did the above experiment on a Dell desktop. However, with the exactly the same hard drive in another computer yet using my company's BIOS, the tsc was still unstable (also only two clocksources：tsc and jiffies, but jiffies was used). I suspect that there was some issue about the BIOS. I know that my BIOS did not support acpi yet, but I am not sure this is the reason.

Hence it jumps to another question: is there some configuration in BIOS can lead to unstable tsc? My BIOS supports Intel CPU and already disables CPU power management.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux - in user applications -, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and don't use *directly* the TSC but use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) (probably with `CLOCK_REALTIME`).

If the computer is connected to the Internet, install some NTPD client daemon.

Comment: I know that, but my team need to run some special hardware tests which depends on these clocksources. When there is no tsc, the tests use jiffies but get inaccurate results. However, if the tsc is not stable, the test result cannot be trusted then.

Comment: So you need to use `clock_gettime(3)` and perhaps `clock_getres(3)`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out in my company tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiment, I made a temporary conclusion: the `tsc` stability is related to ACPI setting. I tested with Aptio BIOS Version 2.15.1236 and standard Linux kernel 3.2.68.

At first, I turned on ACPI in the kernel configuration and build one bzImage whose tsc turned out working well (with other clocksource `acpi_pm` and `hpet`). In addition, even through I tried using `acpi=off` in the kernel command line to disable acpi, clocksource `tsc` still worked well with clocksource `jiffies`.

The second time I turn off ACPI in the kernel configuration. In this time the clocksource `tsc` was unstable in the built kernel image. The only other remaining clocksource is `jiffies`.

After some other experiments, I suspect that tsc is only stable when both BIOS and kernel support ACPI. I checked some forum and was informed that the ACPI was not fully turned off even with `acpi=off` in Linux bootup command line. My company's own BIOS had some bug on ACPI table, and therefore it could not maintain a stable tsc in a Linux kernel image.

However, that is only my guess. I wish there are experts telling me whether I am right or wrong. I will try to fix the ACPI table bugs of my company's BIOS and update the results of my further experiments.